# Join and override a model value using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to override a string ID with a join when doing a query. At the moment I am using the database model as the view model, as Visual Studio automates. This is quite acceptable for my use, but I need to display the username not their ID. For a single candidate I have a achieved it thus for the Details view:

```
var ret = (from c in db.candidates
            where c.candidate_id == id
            join u in db.Users on c.createdby equals u.Id
            select new { c, u.UserName }
            ).FirstOrDefault();

candidate theCandidate = ret.c;
theCandidate.createdby = ret.UserName; // Override with the username
```

Could I have done the `theCandidate.createdby = ret.UserName` within the LINQ query?
Or should I approach this differently?
(it seems to me that creating passing the anonymous type to the view is not ideal)

**Edit**
Or should I just change the database model to have the join implicitly:

```
class Candidate
{
    ...

    [ForeignKey("createdby")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical case that proves the usefulness of ViewModels: your view needs something else compared to what your database delivers.

Also, your code puts something in `createdby` that does not belong there, assuming the datatypes allow it (what if `createdby` is an `int`?)

Perhaps it's time to get used to using this:

```
public class CandidateViewModel
{
    // add properties that the View needs from database candidates table
    string Username { get; set; } // the additional prop

    public CandidateViewModel(candidate c, string username)
    {
        // ... obvious code here
    }
}
```

And then

```
var ret = (from c in db.candidates
           where c.candidate_id == id
           join u in db.Users on c.createdby equals u.Id
           select new CandidateViewModel(c, u.UserName)
          ).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Edit:*

With the new foreign key in place you could try something like this:

```
// using System.Data.Entity;         <-- add this on top
var ret = (from c in db.candidates
           where c.candidate_id == id
           select c
          )
          .Include("CreatedByUser")  // or "createdby" - not sure
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

With that in place, try using `ret.CreatedByUser.UserName` in the controller, or even in the View. Note that my EF is a bit rusty, so you may have to try some things to get it right.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought for a bit ... and then I began wondering, well, if I have to copy every field (where you've written "obvious code") isn't that just as bad? I don't want to write a one-to-one mapping for all the variables. If I add a new one I'll have to add to the db model and view model and then write a line to copy it.

Comment: Or is it good form to just copy (in this case) the candidate from db model to view model:  
`this.candidate = c`

Comment: @noelicus but you can use inheritance here put common properties in base classview model and inherit it and extra property in childclassviewmodel , make sense ?

Comment: Any thoughts on my edit to the question? - seems like a more solid approach to me

Comment: As @Peter suggested,, it is a better design to separate UX concerns from the back end data model by creating ViewModels. If you have lot of properties to map, then you can use AutoMapper library. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper. Think about the cases where you have a good rest api on top of your back end and different consumers want to use the data and perform different tasks. Your UI is one of the consumer and wants to display username.

Comment: Thank you - yes this has helped me understand practical use of viewmodels, which is awesome! - in my case I would appreciate a comment on whether to simply do an implicit join using virtual objects in the db model (as in my edit above) is the best in my case (probably *as well as* doing a view model)?

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, yes that's right. I was at least partly interested in from a design point of view whether one is preferable over another.